# How to make tablet click on textbox to open keyboard with Numbers Not letters?

Tags: asp.net

When i click on textbox that is password txtbox i want to see Numbers not letters and then to swich to Numbers keyboar.Any one know how to do this?

Comment: What tablet? Doesn't seem like an asp.net question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution

```
type="number"
```

add this to your input and this will popup numbers